# Excel VBA Web Scrape column spacing issue. Total line is not in the correct spot

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

[Edit:, inserted html code properly] [edit 2, fixed spacing issue]

spacing issue has been fixed. I copied this line found higher up in the code.

Only thing I would like to do now is have the numbers in the row for totals be bolded, but not sure if that can be singled out in the code. If it can't I'm fine leaving it alone. I just would like that to stand out among the individual employee info.

```
If TD.getAttribute("colspan") Then
                Column = Column + TD.getAttribute("colspan")
```

and placed that into this section lower in the code

```
            Set TDs = TR.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each TD In TDs
                Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value = TD.innerText
                If TD.getAttribute("colspan") Then
                    Column = Column + TD.getAttribute("colspan")

                Else

                Column = Column + 1
                End If
```

Updated code is now

```
Sub DownloadPPAProcessData0700()
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Dim Document As HTMLDocument
Dim Table As IHTMLElement
Dim Tables As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Div As IHTMLElement
Dim Divs As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim H3 As IHTMLElement
Dim TR As IHTMLElement
Dim TRs  As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TD As IHTMLElement
Dim TDs  As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column As Integer

Dim Worksheet As Worksheet

Dim NodeType As String
Dim Warehouse As String
Dim ProcessId As String
Dim PrimaryAttribute As String
Dim SecondaryAttribute As String

Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("0700")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Dim SD As Date
Dim ED As Date
Dim STS As Integer
Dim ETS As Integer
Dim STE As Integer
Dim ETE As Integer
SD = Worksheets("Variables").Range("A2").Value
ED = Worksheets("Variables").Range("A2").Value
STS = Worksheets("Variables").Range("B2").Value
ETS = Worksheets("Variables").Range("C2").Value
STE = Worksheets("Variables").Range("D2").Value
ETE = Worksheets("Variables").Range("D2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

NodeType = Worksheet.Cells(2, 1).Value
Warehouse = Worksheet.Cells(2, 2).Value
ProcessId = Worksheet.Cells(2, 3).Value
PrimaryAttribute = Worksheet.Cells(2, 4).Value
SecondaryAttribute = Worksheet.Cells(2, 5).Value

Row = 1
Column = 1

Sheets("0700").Activate
Sheets("0700").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
With ActiveSheet
Set Browser = New InternetExplorerMedium
Browser.Navigate "https://fclm-portal.amazon.com/ppa/inspect/process?&processId=100114&warehouseId=BFI4&primaryAttribute=PICKING_PROCESS_PATH&secondaryAttribute=GL_CODE&maxIntradayDays=1&spanType=Intraday&startDateIntraday=" & Year(SD) & "%2F" & Month(SD) & "%2F" & Day(SD) & "&startHourIntraday=" & (STS) & "&startMinuteIntraday=" & (STE) & "&endDateIntraday=" & Year(ED) & "%2F" & Month(ED) & "%2F" & Day(ED) & "&endHourIntraday=" & (ETS) & "&endMinuteIntraday=" & (ETE)

'Wait for page to load
Do While Browser.Busy Or Browser.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

'Scan the document
Set Document = Browser.Document
Set Divs = Document.getElementById("secondaryProductivityList").getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each Div In Divs
     Set H3 = Div.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0)

    If Not Div.className = "floatHeader" And Not H3 Is Nothing Then
        Worksheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value = H3.innerText
        Worksheet.Cells(Row, 1).Font.Bold = True
        Row = Row + 1

        Set Tables = Div.getElementsByTagName("table")
        Set Table = Tables(0)
        Set TRs = Table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each TR In TRs
            Column = 1
            Set TDs = TR.getElementsByTagName("th")
            For Each TD In TDs
                Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value = TD.innerText
                Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).Font.Bold = True
                If TD.getAttribute("colspan") Then
                    Column = Column + TD.getAttribute("colspan")
                Else
                    Column = Column + 1
                End If
                Next

            Set TDs = TR.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each TD In TDs
                Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value = TD.innerText
                If TD.getAttribute("colspan") Then
                    Column = Column + TD.getAttribute("colspan")

                Else

                Column = Column + 1
                End If


                Next
        Row = Row + 1
        Next
    End If

 Row = Row + 1
 Next
 Browser.Quit
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End With
 Range("A1:Z50").Columns.AutoFit
 End Sub
```

I am trying to work on a web scrape file, the webpage changes depending on the time of day you want to get info for. but for now I will just post how the code for 1 hour is set up.

This does copy the correct tables from the webpage but the problem I am having is that at the end of each table there should be a total Line, that should match up spacing wise with the other numbers. the word "total" on the webpage takes up 3 column, spaces and then the rest of the numbers will follow after and line up with the "units" column.

when the macro pulls data, it is placing the total line in the left most cell, and the number data right after it. causing the whole line to be off by two cells.

Including 2 links to images of what the web page looks like and what the excel file spits out

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZqxU.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMER1.jpg

here is the code

```
Sub DownloadPPAProcessData0700()
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Dim Document As HTMLDocument
Dim Table As IHTMLElement
Dim Tables As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Div As IHTMLElement
Dim Divs As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim H3 As IHTMLElement
Dim TR As IHTMLElement
Dim TRs  As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TD As IHTMLElement
Dim TDs  As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column As Integer

Dim Worksheet As Worksheet



Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("0700")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim SD As Date
Dim ED As Date
Dim STS As Integer
Dim ETS As Integer
Dim STE As Integer
Dim ETE As Integer
SD = Worksheets("Variables").Range("A2").Value
ED = Worksheets("Variables").Range("A2").Value
STS = Worksheets("Variables").Range("B2").Value
ETS = Worksheets("Variables").Range("C2").Value
STE = Worksheets("Variables").Range("D2").Value
ETE = Worksheets("Variables").Range("D2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Row = 1
Column = 1

Sheets("0700").Activate
Sheets("0700").Select
With ActiveSheet
Set Browser = New InternetExplorerMedium
Browser.Navigate "https://fclm.com/ppa/inspect/process?&processId=100114&warehouseId=...&primaryAttribute=PICKING_PROCESS_PATH&secondaryAttribute=GL_CODE&maxIntradayDays=1&spanType=Intraday&startDateIntraday=" & Year(SD) & "%2F" & Month(SD) & "%2F" & Day(SD) & "&startHourIntraday=" & (STS) & "&startMinuteIntraday=" & (STE) & "&endDateIntraday=" & Year(ED) & "%2F" & Month(ED) & "%2F" & Day(ED) & "&endHourIntraday=" & (ETS) & "&endMinuteIntraday=" & (ETE)

'Wait for page to load
Do While Browser.Busy Or Browser.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

'Scan the document
Set Document = Browser.Document
Set Divs = Document.getElementById("secondaryProductivityList").getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each Div In Divs
    Set H3 = Div.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0)

    If Not Div.className = "floatHeader" And Not H3 Is Nothing Then
        Worksheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value = H3.innerText
        Row = Row + 1

        Set Tables = Div.getElementsByTagName("table")
        Set Table = Tables(0)
        Set TRs = Table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each TR In TRs
            Column = 1
            Set TDs = TR.getElementsByTagName("th")
            For Each TD In TDs
                Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value = TD.innerText
                Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).Font.Bold = True
                If TD.getAttribute("colspan") Then
                    Column = Column + TD.getAttribute("colspan")
                Else
                    Column = Column + 1
                End If
                Next

            Set TDs = TR.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each TD In TDs
                Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value = TD.innerText
                Column = Column + 1
                Next

        Row = Row + 1
        Next
    End If
Row = Row + 1
Next

Browser.Quit
End With
Range("A1:Z50").Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

This is the inspect code for the whole bottom tables I am trying to copy from.

```html
<div id="secondaryProductivityList">
  <div>
    <h3>PICKING_PROCESS_PATH: PPFRACSDESTROY</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3" class="header"></th>
          <th colspan="7" class="header">UNKNOWN</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="header">Employee&nbsp;Id</th>
          <th class="header">Employee&nbsp;Name</th>
          <th class="header">Manager&nbsp;Name</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Units</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Quantity</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Direct)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Inferred)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Total)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">UPH</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">QPH</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="100244269">100244269</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="100244269">Llarenas, Brandon</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101151204">Jackson, Michelle M</td>
          <td>503</td>
          <td>503</td>
          <td>0.92</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0.92</td>
          <td>545.75</td>
          <td>545.75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101157611">101157611</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101157611">Swearingen, Caitlin</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101151204">Jackson, Michelle M</td>
          <td>539</td>
          <td>539</td>
          <td>0.99</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0.99</td>
          <td>543.38</td>
          <td>543.38</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="totalLineItem">Total:</td>
          <td>1,042</td>
          <td>1,042</td>
          <td>1.91</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>1.91</td>
          <td>544.52</td>
          <td>544.52</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div class="floatHeader" style="display:none">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 1170px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3" class="header" style="width: 459.233px;"></th>
            <th colspan="7" class="header" style="width: 688.233px;">UNKNOWN</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="header" style="width: 110.233px;">Employee&nbsp;Id</th>
            <th class="header" style="width: 160.233px;">Employee&nbsp;Name</th>
            <th class="header" style="width: 167.233px;">Manager&nbsp;Name</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 49.2333px;">Units</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 77.2333px;">Quantity</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 124.233px;">Hours (Direct)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 141.233px;">Hours (Inferred)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 115.233px;">Hours (Total)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 59.2333px;">UPH</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 59.2333px;">QPH</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>PICKING_PROCESS_PATH: PPFRACSDESTROYHZMT</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3" class="header"></th>
          <th colspan="7" class="header">UNKNOWN</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="header">Employee&nbsp;Id</th>
          <th class="header">Employee&nbsp;Name</th>
          <th class="header">Manager&nbsp;Name</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Units</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Quantity</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Direct)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Inferred)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Total)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">UPH</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">QPH</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="100244269">100244269</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="100244269">Llarenas, Brandon</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101151204">Jackson, Michelle M</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>0.08</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0.08</td>
          <td>280.85</td>
          <td>280.85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101157611">101157611</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101157611">Swearingen, Caitlin</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101151204">Jackson, Michelle M</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>0.01</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0.01</td>
          <td>620.69</td>
          <td>620.69</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="totalLineItem">Total:</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>0.09</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0.09</td>
          <td>312.54</td>
          <td>312.54</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div class="floatHeader" style="display:none">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 1170px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3" class="header" style="width: 459.233px;"></th>
            <th colspan="7" class="header" style="width: 688.233px;">UNKNOWN</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="header" style="width: 110.233px;">Employee&nbsp;Id</th>
            <th class="header" style="width: 160.233px;">Employee&nbsp;Name</th>
            <th class="header" style="width: 167.233px;">Manager&nbsp;Name</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 49.2333px;">Units</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 77.2333px;">Quantity</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 124.233px;">Hours (Direct)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 141.233px;">Hours (Inferred)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 115.233px;">Hours (Total)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 59.2333px;">UPH</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 59.2333px;">QPH</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>PICKING_PROCESS_PATH: PPFRACSLTL</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3" class="header"></th>
          <th colspan="7" class="header">UNKNOWN</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="header">Employee&nbsp;Id</th>
          <th class="header">Employee&nbsp;Name</th>
          <th class="header">Manager&nbsp;Name</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Units</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Quantity</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Direct)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Inferred)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">Hours (Total)</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">UPH</th>
          <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header">QPH</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101158899">101158899</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101158899">Cimafranca, Lorna</td>
          <td class="employeeInspect" id="101151204">Jackson, Michelle M</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>57</td>
          <td>0.80</td>
          <td>0.20</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>57</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="totalLineItem">Total:</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>57</td>
          <td>0.80</td>
          <td>0.20</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>57</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div class="floatHeader" style="display:none">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 1170px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3" class="header" style="width: 468.233px;"></th>
            <th colspan="7" class="header" style="width: 679.233px;">UNKNOWN</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="header" style="width: 115.233px;">Employee&nbsp;Id</th>
            <th class="header" style="width: 159.233px;">Employee&nbsp;Name</th>
            <th class="header" style="width: 173.233px;">Manager&nbsp;Name</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 51.2333px;">Units</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 80.2333px;">Quantity</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 129.233px;">Hours (Direct)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 146.233px;">Hours (Inferred)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 119.233px;">Hours (Total)</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 43.2333px;">UPH</th>
            <th class="{sorter: 'thousands'} header" style="width: 44.2333px;">QPH</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code. Look at what's happening when you are fetching the *total* portion of the page.

Comment: As usual <sigh> I can't view imgur images - just black screen. Do you have actual urls we can test with please? You can use the snippet tool via [edit] for inserting HTML.

Comment: I'd like to post the url but sadly outside of our worknetwork the links will not connect. That is one thing causing this to be even more of a challenge

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to use your answer/code and implement that into my file. I am pretty new to excel still and this code was found in another file that someone else made I just made some adjustments to the url link to work with parameters. I did however fix the spacing issue a different way. I'll add it into my question edit

Answer (score 1):

I would use the clipboard to copy across the formatting. I am reading your html from file (edited that part out now) whereas you would extract data from `ie.document` - outline shown below.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, tables As Object, i As Long, clipboard As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tablesDescriptions As Object
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, url As String
    url = "yourURL"
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer 'InternetExplorerMedium
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate2 url
    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Set html = ie.document
    Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("#secondaryProductivityList table")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set tablesDescriptions = html.querySelectorAll("#secondaryProductivityList h3")
    ws.Cells.UnMerge

    For i = 0 To tables.Length - 1 Step 2
        clipboard.SetText tables.item(i).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 2, 1) = tablesDescriptions.item(IIf(i = 0, 0, i / 2)).innerText
        ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
    Next
    ie.Quit
End Sub

Public Function LastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

**Output:**

[image]